# Low cost PCI Express development board

Tags: pcie

I'm looking for a low cost (less than $100) board with a PCI Express (x1) interface and with some kind of a programmable CPU that can use that interface. I don't need anything fancy, just something that can do PCI Express for some experiments but I can't build the board myself.

Does anybody know where I can get such a board?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lattice [has a $99 one](http://www.latticesemi.com/products/fpga/ecp3/ecp3surgepromotions.cfm) if you can live with a soft-core CPU.

Comment: Thanks. One issue that I can see is that the license for their software is free for use only until July 31st, 2012 and after that it is something like $900. I suppose if I load the soft CPU before that and just leave it there it might be OK (if I understand the licensing scheme correctly) but it still seems a bit risky.